# Is itunesconnect.apple.com the only way to upload screenshots?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is there a better way to upload screenshots to iTunes connect other than using the web interface at `itunesconnect.apple.com`?

When you have an app localised to multiple languages, it can take hours to upload all screenshots to iTunes Connect. If you have a universal app localised to say 4 languages, with a Pro and Lite version, that ends up being `2 * 4 * (5 + 5 + 5) = 120 screenshots`!

Comment: Such is the way of the world.  You shouldn't have chosen to release so many apps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is the only way..

> I figured out why iTunes Connect sucks so bad: Palm stole Apple employees, so Apple stole Microsoft employees to run it. Mystery solved. [http://nikf.org](http://nikf.org/post/206123480/i-figured-out-why-itunes-connect-sucks-so-bad)

Btw, in case you'll stumble upon [ApplicationLoader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/9_UsingApplicationLoader/UsingApplicationLoader.html).. it is not possible to it use for this.